# ¿Por qué da error al instalar este módulo de odoo?

Tags: mvc, odoo

estoy instalando un modulo de odoo pero no me permite instalarlo selecciono el modulo y se actualiza como si se hubiera instalado pero en la terminal manda un error de unas dependencias nose que que dependencias tenga que instalar para que no mande ese error

Adjunto imagen del modulo y del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el modulo que quiero instalar pero no la terminal manda un error

[image]
manda un error de dependecias que dependencias le tendria que instalar para que funcione y no mande e se errror

Comment: ese modulo es el que estoy tratando de instalar y no me deja osea lo instalo se actyualuiza y cuando veo no se instalo

Comment: Tienes razón, mala mía. Has revisado su puedes subir la versión de Odoo (sin que ponga lío por tu versión del sistema operativo)?

Comment: estoy ocupando la version 14 porquelo probe con la 15 y ese modulo creo que no existe en la version 15

Comment: Esta es la v14 https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/14.0/mgmtsystem_quality/. Que versión de odoo tienes instalada?

Comment: tengo instalada la version 14

Comment: y manda ese error cuando instalo el modulo y cuando voy a las apss aparece como cancel installing

Comment: la carpeta que descarego tengo que meterla en mi proyecto? @Legna?

Comment: Si, pero uno de los warnings dice que el modulo no es instalable. Descargarlo de nuevo desde el link que te pase para descartar que esté corrupto. Como tienes tu `odoo.conf` Tienes que señalar desde ahí donde quieres poner tus modulos personalizados.

Comment: los tengo ne la carpeta customs_addons

Comment: [options]

admin_password = 
db_host=localhost
db_port=5432
db_user=
db_password=
addons_path=/opt/odoo3.0/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo3.0/odoo/customs_addons

Comment: asi tengo el .conf

Comment: Está bien, es correcto.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140274/discussion-between-carlos-baez-and-legna).